# Sequelize nested include

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I have a table User, Professor and Subject. A professor is linked to a user and a professor can have many subjects (junction table with ProfessorSubjects). When a user fills the form to sign up as a professor, I want my backend to automatically create the professor linked to the user and the subjects for this professor. For now, I have this:

```
    static signUp = async (data) => {
        data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10);
        data.status = "PENDING";
        data.confirmationCode = jwt.sign({ email: data.email }, config.secret);
    
        await UserModel.create(data, { include: ProfessorModel });
    };
```

First of all, the User is created correctly but there is no creation of the professor and the link. How to correct the include to create the professor + link and the subjects + link?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add model definitions and associations